# generate name with random numbers in an excel file

Tags: python

I have an excel file that I open like this:

```
excel_file = pd.read_excel('/documents/workspace/Sheet3.xlsx')
```

then I save the file like this:

```
workbook.save('/documents/workspace/Sheet3.xlsx')
```

I would like the filename to be added random numbers in it. I tried to do it like this:

```
workbook.save('/documents/workspace/Sheet3.xlsx').random.ranrange(1,99999)
```

but couldn't. it said that the object of type NoneType does not have the attribute random or randrange. can anybody help me? I can save the file normally without putting this option to generate the random numbers

Comment: It's generally a very bad idea to generate random file names using a method like you're proposing, because you run the risk of generating the same number twice. Have you considered uuids instead? If you must use random numbers, look at formatted strings and use something like `f'Sheet{random.randint(1,99999)}.xlsx'`

Comment: @Grismar Thank you! served! just a question: I make several requests to send this worksheet for registration on a website. and in my code the way I managed to make these various requests synchronously was to load this excel at each beginning of a request. when I put it like that, it doesn't recognize because the number was generated randomly. is there a way around this?

Comment: From your description alone, it's impossible to say - some ideas are to generate a unique name when making the request and basing the response and filename on that, or coming up with some scheme to generate a unique name that's not random. But you should probably turn that question into an entirely new question.